# How to stub a class which returns a class?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon

I have a method which i'm unit testing and i'm trying to test both

```
    ...
    let db = new MockDb()
    ...
    db.query(query)
        .then(cursor => {
          return cursor.next()
            .then(result => {
              if (result !== undefined || !data.id) { <-- WANT TO STUB CURSOR.NEXT() SO I CAN TEST RESULT BEING DIFFERENT VALUES
                data.id = uuidv4()
              }
    ...
```

I have this file that is used for mocking/stubbing which contains 2 classes, but only exposes one of them

```
class MockDb {  
  query (aql) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      return resolve(new MockCursor())
    })
  }
}


class MockCursor {
  next () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      return resolve({foo: 'bar'})
    })
  }
}

module.exports = MockDb
```

How can I stub what `cursor.next()` returns in this case?

Does NOT work - gives error `TypeError: cursor.stub is not a function`

```
before(() => {
  let cursor = sinon.stub()
  cursor.stub('next').return(undefined)
  sinon.stub(db, 'query').resolves(cursor)
})
```

If i expose the `MockCursor` class I can simply do this:

```
let db = new MockDb()
let cursor = new MockCursor()
sinon.stub(cursor, 'next').resolves(undefined)
sinon.stub(db, 'query').resolves(cursor)
```

But i was just trying to do it without having to expose the MockCursor class explicitly

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
const cursor = sinon
  .stub()
  .returns({
    next: () => Promise.resolve(undefined)
  });
sinon.stub(db, 'query').resolves(cursor);
```